# Can you have a Change Status button on the Cases List View in Lightning?

Tags: custom-button, list-view, lightning-action

In Salesforce Classic, my users had the "Change Status" button on their list views, which would change the Status of multiple cases regardless of record type:
[image: Change Status Classic]

Now it seems that in Lightning, there is only one way to update Status values in mass, by specifying a Case Record Type in the List View filters and using the inline edit available once that filter is active:
[image: No Change Status in Lightning]

Is there any way to create a custom button or Lightning Action that will update the Status of multiple cases on a List View like my users had in Classic?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set up [Mass Quick Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mass_quick_actions_create.htm&type=5). In the Object Manager, first go in and create a Quick Action, then add it to your Search Layout. This allows you to create custom Quick Actions for (most) list views and objects.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to have worked for me. Unfortunately it appears that setup MSP is not available in Lightning Setup... I had to go to Classic to find it LOL!!

Comment: @runningman Lightning is still catching up to Classic, it should be there soon. Glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, we can have 'Change Status' button on the cases(standard object) list view in lightning, firstly we need to understand that 'Change Status' is a quick action and it was default quick action in Classic but once we switch to lightning, it doesn't seems to be default actions in lightning.
So, we need to create 'Change Status' action in lightning and then we have to add it in the 'selected quick actions' from list view button layout of case object.